# Image into chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Hi I have a image and I need to create a chart same as it is. can any one let me know in which tenchnology can i create a charts which can look the same

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['',''],
          ['',27],
          ['',25],
          ['',60],
          ['',31],
          ['',25],        
          ['',39],        
          ['',25],
          ['',31],
          ['',26],
          ['',28],        
          ['',80],          
          ['',28],
          ['',27],
          ['',31],
          ['',27],        
          ['',29],        
          ['',26],
          ['',35],
          ['',70],
          ['',25]             
        ]);
        var options = {   
                backgroundColor: {
                    stroke: '#4322c0',
                    strokeWidth: 3},
                'is3D':true,
                series: {0:{color:'#DF013A',lineWidth:2}},
                colors:['#D8D8D8'],
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                legend: {position: 'none'}
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are creating a report you should check out Jasper reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/chartgraphs/) about creating different types of graphs using Java.

You might also be interested in [this one](http://www.chartjs.org/).

Another ones are [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) and  [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/)

Comment: I need to create a chart using html and javascript,Please let me know if any javascript charts are avaliable which show me same look

Comment: I see, your tag was java first, thats why I provided java samples. In that case, disregard the first link of my answer. In other ones you can find plenty of examples. Investigate them to find the one which suits your needs.

Comment: I tired with google charts but i didnt get the exact view of it

Comment: I suppose it would be good if you could explain the chart, what do today: zero and 53 mean? Also please share your current result so we can find out how far did you make progress and how far is it from your expectation.

Comment: it is just a text on the chart, I wnat the chart line to be green colour and body as gray which looks same in the image, I have updated the code please check out